# How to insert the file path as a function parameter in RainTPL template engine

Tags: php, template-engine

I don't know what can I do it.
I have a structure function as like the following:

**Example: (PHP)**

```
function func($file_path){
  // my code
return array;
}
```

I want to use the previous function in my template file, but the problem in `$file_path` parameter, I done the following in my template file:

**Example (Template File)**

```
{loop name="Pics"}
  {if="$value.pic_id == $picID"}
     <a href="#">{$uploadFolder}/{$value.pic_name | func}</a>
  {/if}
{/loop}
```

**Note:**
`$uploadFolder` is a folder contain files, and `value.pic_name` is the file name

Now when implement this code occurs the following problem:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory .

As we see the reason behind that problem is the function parameter does not work fine.
I'm sure the problem inside this area.

```
{$uploadFolder}/{$value.pic_name | func}
```

Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. It is simple and read the documentation so that it will becleared to you.

```
RainTPL::base_url['path'];
```